# Delete ActionResult .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I get error 'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int?' on this line

```
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

I haven't tried anything except this method so far.

```
  public class EditProfileController : Controller
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
    private object _context;

    public EditProfileController(ApplicationDbContext Db)
    {
        db = Db;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      List<ApplicationUser> listdata = db.Users
        .Select(user => new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Id =  user.Id,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            NormalizedUserName = user.NormalizedUserName,
                            Email = user.Email


            // Add the remainder properties
        }).ToList();
    return View(listdata);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        //Get user and return the Edit View
        ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id)
      .Select(u => new ApplicationUser()
      {
          Id = u.Id,
          UserName = u.UserName,
          NormalizedUserName = u.NormalizedUserName,
          Email = u.Email

          // Add the remainder properties
      }).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(user);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ApplicationUser listdata)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(listdata).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(listdata);
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var user = await db.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(user);
    }


    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
     {
        var user = await db.Users.FindAsync(id);
        db.Users.Remove(user);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
  }
```

My expected results are when i click on the Delete link on the View page that it asks to confirm deletion and then once I click Yes or No it performs the DeleteConfirmed Action. What do I need to fix this error?

Comment: The error is clear and points to a problem in the code. Is the `id` a string or integer? It can't be both. Use the correct type.

Comment: The default primary key column type for `IdentityUser`  is a string, not an int. You can *make* it an int if you prefer, but that's not the default. Also, FWIW, you should always manage users with `UserManager<TUser>`, rather than using the context directly as you are. It does a number of things behind the scenes when creating users and such, that your app code shouldn't concern itself with (such as normalizing username and emails). You can select users via the context, but standard CRUD should happen via the manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Delete(int? id)` to `Delete(string id)` and `DeleteConfirmed(int id)` to `DeleteConfirmed(string id)` as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id) // <-- Here it is
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var user = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id) // <-- Here it is
{
    var user = await db.Users.FindAsync(id);
    db.Users.Remove(user);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```